# Using awk/sed to parse out multiple strings from a MySQL error

Tags: mysql, bash, sed

I have a bash script that needs to identify some important sub-strings within a MySQL error generated from a `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G` command run from the terminal.  In particular, the line starting with `Last_Error: ...` is of significant importance.  As as example, if the line read (broken into multiple lines for ease of reading):

```
Last_Error: Error 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint
fails (`dms/active_sessions`, CONSTRAINT `active_sessions_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY
(`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)' 
on query. Default database: 'dms'. Query: 'INSERT INTO active_sessions
(session_id,user_id,lastused,ip) VALUES ('749d9d494c31ab8ee76bf6b6b1127fd2',
'15389','2011-09-27 14:04:59','172.16.11.31')'
```

Assuming the error string is stored in a variable $LAST_ERROR, I've used the following three variables to store `user_id`, the field in the table with the FK constraint, `users`, the table that is being referenced by the FK, and `id` which is the key in `users` that is being referenced:

```
FIELD=`echo $LAST_ERROR | sed 's/.*FOREIGN KEY [\(\`]*\([0-9a-zA-Z_-]*\)[\`\)]*.*/\1/'`
TABLE=`echo $LAST_ERROR | sed 's/.*REFERENCES \`\([0-9a-zA-Z_-]*\)\`.*/\1/'`
COLUMN=`echo $LAST_ERROR | sed 's/.*REFERENCES \`['$TABLE']*\` [\(\`]*\([0-9a-zA-Z_-]*\)[\`\)]*.*/\1/'`
```

Are these three variables and their sed commands an acceptable way of finding the values?  With those variables defined, I need to parse through the SQL query in the error.  The only variable that pertains to this specific case (the rest are being used elsewhere in the script) is `$FIELD`.  In this case, I need to identify that if the fields specified in the SQL query are:

```
(session_id,user_id,lastused,ip)
```

That `$FIELD` is the 4th field listed in the SQL query, and it's corresponding value in:

```
('749d9d494c31ab8ee76bf6b6b1127fd2','15389','2011-09-27 14:04:59','172.16.11.31')
```

is `15389`.  What sed/awk commands can reference the fields listed in the SQL query, and find the corresponding values in the latter part of the query?

Comment: This is a rather extensive question.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've edited my question, thus far I've found the values of `user_id` and `id` using awk, although I'm not entirely certain as to whether this is the preferred method to tackle that.

Comment: This will give you the user_id: cat error.txt|tr '\n' ' '|sed s/'.*VALUES'//|awk -F , '{print $2,$3,$4}'|tr "'" " "|tr ")" " "|awk '{print $1}'

Comment: I managed to parse out the three variables I needed to the best of my ability.  I am not entirely certain if the approach I took is ideal or not.  Now I just need to use the `$FIELD` variable to parse out the SQL query and determine the value being inserted for `$FIELD`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Superficially, this `sed` script would list the parts you request:

```
sed 's/.* FOREIGN KEY (\([^)]*\)) REFERENCES \([^(]*\) (\([^)]*\)) .*/(\1) \2 (\3)/'
```

on the not altogether implausible assumption that you do not use either open or close parentheses in your table and column names.  The output is unambiguous and deals with a list of columns referencing another list of columns.

Comment: I managed to split them up into three separate sed commands, and have edited my original question to reflect them.  I'm not entirely convinced though that my approach is ideal.  What are your thoughts?

Comment: I'd probably use a single command like mine for this one item - probably with an appropriate pattern to do the substitute for the lines that matched, and probably with a `sed -n` to suppress normal printing and then add a `p` after the substitute to print the 3-part match.